# Why does my app fetch API data every time I enter a character in my TextField view in my SwiftUI app

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have a basic SwiftUI app that is behaving very strangely. The app basically offers the user choices on how to download cocktail information from a public API. One of the choices is to download all cocktails containing a given ingredient which the user types in to a TextField view. But every time I type a character of the ingredient in the TextField, my ViewModel class is initialised prior to downloading cocktail data. It seems the NavigationLink is being activated every time I type a character into the TextField.

Here is my IngredientView struct containing the TextField and NavigationLink views

```
//
//  IngredientView.swift
//  Cocktail Heaven
//
//  Created by Stephen Learmonth on 03/11/2021.
//

import SwiftUI

struct IngredientView: View {
    
    @State var enteredIngredient: String = ""
    @State var ingredientIsEntered: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.systemTeal)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            VStack(spacing: 5.0) {
                Text("Please enter the ingredient you want to search for.")
                    .padding(50.0)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 20.0))
                    .navigationTitle("Search by Ingredient")
                
                TextField("Ingredient", text: $enteredIngredient)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .frame(width: 250.0, height: 60.0, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                NavigationLink(isActive: $ingredientIsEntered) {
                    DetailsView(viewModel: ViewModel(urlString: "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?i=\(enteredIngredient)", dataType: "Ingredients"))
                } label: {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                
                Button {
                    if !enteredIngredient.isEmpty
                    {
                        ingredientIsEntered = true
                    }
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("Continue")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 25.0))
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: 250.0)
                }
                .background(.blue)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30.0))
                
            }
        }
    }
}




struct IngredientView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        IngredientView()
    }
}
```

Here is my ViewModel class;

```
//
//  ViewModel.swift
//  Cocktail Heaven
//
//  Created by Stephen Learmonth on 26/10/2021.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewModel {
    
    var dataType: String
    var urlString: String
    var drinks: Drinks = Drinks(drinks: [Cocktail]())
    var ingredients: Ingredients = Ingredients(ingredients: [Ingredient]())
    var alcohols: Alcohols = Alcohols(drinks: [Alcohol]())
    var dataIsFound: Bool = true
    
    init(urlString: String, dataType: String) {
        self.urlString = urlString
        self.dataType = dataType
        FetchData()
    }
    
    func FetchData() {
        switch dataType {
        case "Drinks":
            let networkManager = NetworkManager<Drinks>()
            networkManager.fetchData(urlString) { results, error in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    guard let resultsSafe = results else { return }
                    self.drinks = resultsSafe
                    self.dataIsFound = !error
                }
            }
            
        case "Ingredients":
            let networkManager = NetworkManager<Drinks>()
            let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".map { String($0) }
            let baseUrl = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f="
            
            // Extract ingredient from the URL
            var ingredient = urlString.drop { character in
                return character != "="
            }
            ingredient.removeFirst()
            print("DEBUG: \(ingredient)")
            
            //             Search cocktails for those with the named ingredient
            if !ingredient.isEmpty {
                var callCount = 0
                
                // Use for-in loop to fetch all the cocktails by first letter
                self.drinks = Drinks(drinks: [Cocktail]())
                for letter in letters {
                    let url = baseUrl + letter
                    networkManager.fetchData(String(url)) { results, error in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            guard let resultsSafe = results else { callCount += 1;
                                                                   self.dataIsFound = self.dataIsFound && error;
                                                                   return }
                            self.drinks.drinks.append(contentsOf: resultsSafe.drinks)
                            callCount += 1
                            self.dataIsFound = self.dataIsFound && error
                            if callCount == 26 {
                                
                                // Return filtered cocktails
                                let cocktails = self.drinks.drinks.filter { cocktail in
                                    let ingredientIsPresent =
                                    cocktail.strIngredient1?.contains(ingredient) ?? false ||
                                    cocktail.strIngredient2?.contains(ingredient) ?? false ||
                                    cocktail.strIngredient3?.contains(ingredient) ?? false ||
                                    cocktail.strIngredient4?.contains(ingredient) ?? false ||
                                    cocktail.strIngredient5?.contains(ingredient) ?? false ||
                                    cocktail.strIngredient6?.contains(ingredient) ?? false ||
                                    cocktail.strIngredient7?.contains(ingredient) ?? false ||
                                    cocktail.strIngredient8?.contains(ingredient) ?? false ||
                                    cocktail.strIngredient9?.contains(ingredient) ?? false ||
                                    cocktail.strIngredient10?.contains(ingredient) ?? false ||
                                    cocktail.strIngredient11?.contains(ingredient) ?? false ||
                                    cocktail.strIngredient12?.contains(ingredient) ?? false
                                    print("DEBUG: \(ingredient); \(ingredientIsPresent)")
                                    return ingredientIsPresent
                                }
                                if cocktails.count > 0 {
                                    self.drinks.drinks = cocktails
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        case "Alcohols":
            let networkManager = NetworkManager<Alcohols>()
            networkManager.fetchData(urlString) { results, error in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    guard let resultsSafe = results else { return }
                    self.alcohols = resultsSafe
                    self.dataIsFound = !error
                }
            }
            
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    
    func buildIngredients(_ cocktail: Cocktail) -> [String] {
        var ingredients:[String] = []
        
        if let ingredient1 = cocktail.strIngredient1 {
            ingredients.append(ingredient1)
        }
        if let ingredient2 = cocktail.strIngredient2 {
            ingredients.append(ingredient2)
        }
        if let ingredient3 = cocktail.strIngredient3 {
            ingredients.append(ingredient3)
        }
        if let ingredient4 = cocktail.strIngredient4 {
            ingredients.append(ingredient4)
        }
        if let ingredient5 = cocktail.strIngredient5 {
            ingredients.append(ingredient5)
        }
        if let ingredient6 = cocktail.strIngredient6 {
            ingredients.append(ingredient6)
        }
        if let ingredient7 = cocktail.strIngredient7 {
            ingredients.append(ingredient7)
        }
        if let ingredient8 = cocktail.strIngredient8 {
            ingredients.append(ingredient8)
        }
        if let ingredient9 = cocktail.strIngredient9 {
            ingredients.append(ingredient9)
        }
        if let ingredient10 = cocktail.strIngredient10 {
            ingredients.append(ingredient10)
        }
        if let ingredient11 = cocktail.strIngredient11 {
            ingredients.append(ingredient11)
        }
        if let ingredient12 = cocktail.strIngredient12 {
            ingredients.append(ingredient12)
        }
        
        return ingredients
    }
}
```

and here is my DetailsView struct;

```
//
//  DetailsView.swift
//  Cocktail Heaven
//
//  Created by Stephen Learmonth on 20/10/2021.
//

import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI
import UIKit

struct DetailsView: View {
    
    var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if viewModel.dataType == "Drinks" {
            
            List(viewModel.drinks.drinks) { cocktail in
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text(cocktail.strDrink + "  -")
                            .frame(alignment: .center)
                        Text(cocktail.strAlcoholic)
                            .frame(alignment: .center)
                    }
                    
                    WebImage(url: URL(string: cocktail.strDrinkThumb))
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(alignment: .center)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    
                    Text("~ Ingredients List ~\n").frame(alignment: .center)
                    
                    ForEach(viewModel.buildIngredients(cocktail), id: \.self) { ingredient in
                        Text(ingredient)
                    }
                    
                    Text("\n~ Recipe Instructions ~\n\n")
                    
                    Text(cocktail.strInstructions + "\n").fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color(.systemTeal))
                .background(Color(.systemTeal))
            }
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
        if viewModel.dataType == "Ingredients" {
            
            List(viewModel.drinks.drinks) { cocktail in
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text(cocktail.strDrink + "  -")
                            .frame(alignment: .center)
                        Text(cocktail.strAlcoholic)
                            .frame(alignment: .center)
                    }
                    
                    WebImage(url: URL(string: cocktail.strDrinkThumb))
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(alignment: .center)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    
                    Text("~ Ingredients List ~\n").frame(alignment: .center)
                    
                    ForEach(viewModel.buildIngredients(cocktail), id: \.self) { ingredient in
                        Text(ingredient)
                    }
                    
                    Text("\n~ Recipe Instructions ~\n\n")
                    
                    Text(cocktail.strInstructions + "\n").fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color(.systemTeal))
                .background(Color(.systemTeal))
            }
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)

        }
        
        if viewModel.dataType == "Alcohols" {
            List(viewModel.alcohols.drinks) { alcohol in
                VStack {
                    Text(" ~ \(alcohol.strDrink) ~ \n")
                    
                    WebImage(url: URL(string: alcohol.strDrinkThumb))
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(alignment: .center)
                        .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fill)
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}




struct DetailsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailsView(viewModel: ViewModel(urlString: "www.google.com", dataType: ""))
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the view model gets initiated every time SwiftUI updates the view and because you make an API call in the view model init.

Comment: Each time your `ViewModel` goes through its `init` (which can potentially happen each time the parent view is re-rendered), you call `FetchData`. Easiest option is touse `onAppear` rather than `init` to call `FetchData`

Comment: But surely the view model can only get initiated when the NavigationLink gets activated and that can only happen when the button is tapped surely?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Have you read my latest comment on this issue. Would really appreciate your help as I am not an expert on SwiftUI.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Here is a link to my public repo if you would like to download the project and run it. Thanks.https://github.com/sjlearmonth/Cocktail-Heaven

Comment: Did you try to use onAppear instead as suggested?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't see how using onAppear is going to stop the NavigationLink being activated every time a character is typed into the TextView.

Comment: It won't, if that is what you want then you need to redesign your solution