# Creating an array from stuct data SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, struct, swiftui

First of all, i am very sorry for the noob question, but i just cant seem to figure this out.

I am very new to coding and just started to get my feet wet with SwiftUI, following a few courses and started to dabble in trying to create some basic apps.

I am currently working on an app that does an API call and displays the data.

My issue is, im trying to put the decoded data into an array, it sounds so simple and I think i am missing something very easy, but for the life of me I cant seem to figure it out.

Below is the codable struct I have

```
struct Drinks: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let strDrink : String
    let strInstructions: String
    let strDrinkThumb: String?
    let strIngredient1: String?
    let strIngredient2: String?
    let strIngredient3: String?
    let strIngredient4: String?
    let strIngredient5: String?
}
```

I want to put the ingredients into an Array so I can go through them in lists etc

```
import SwiftUI

struct IngredientView: View {
    let drink : Drinks
    let ingredientArray : [String] = [] // I want to append the ingredients here
    var body: some View {
        GroupBox() {
            DisclosureGroup("Drink Ingredience") {
                ForEach(0..<3) { item in
                    Divider().padding(.vertical, 2)
                    HStack {
                        Group {
                            // To use the array here
                        }
                        .font(Font.system(.body).bold())
                        Spacer(minLength: 25)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, sorry for the noob question that probably has a simple answer, but worth a shot asking :D

Thanks!

Comment: The design of the JSON being `strIngredient1`, `strIngredient2`, etc. is not a good idea. You should have all those ingredients already in an array, as it can be any length.

Comment: The ingrediens are probably part of the api at (example): 
https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita

See also this SO question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69931557/why-does-my-app-fetch-api-data-every-time-i-enter-a-character-in-my-textfield-vi

and his related github project:
https://github.com/sjlearmonth/Cocktail-Heaven

You should be able to work it out from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this approach to get all your ingredients into an array and use
it in Lists. The idea is to use a function to gather all your ingredients into an array of
`Ingredient` objects. You could also use a computed property.
It is best to use a `Ingredient` object and declare it `Identifiable`
so that when you use them in list and ForEach, each one will be
unique, even if the names are the same.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var drinkList = [Drink]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(drinkList) { drink in
                VStack {
                    Text(drink.strDrink).foregroundColor(.blue)
                    Text(drink.strInstructions)
                    ForEach(drink.allIngredients()) { ingr in
                        HStack {
                            Text(ingr.name).foregroundColor(.red)
                            Text(ingr.amount).foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            let theResponse: ApiResponse? = await getData(from: "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita")
            if let response = theResponse {
                drinkList = response.drinks
            }
       }
    }
    
    func getData<T: Decodable>(from urlString: String) async -> T? {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print(URLError(.badURL))
            return nil // <-- todo, deal with errors
        }
        do {
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: URLRequest(url: url))
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                print(URLError(.badServerResponse))
                return nil // <-- todo, deal with errors
            }
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        }
        catch {
            print("---> error: \(error)")
            return nil // <-- todo, deal with errors
        }
    }
    
}

struct ApiResponse: Decodable {
    var drinks: [Drink]
}
    
struct Drink: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let idDrink: String
    let strDrink: String
    let strDrinkThumb: String
    let strAlcoholic: String
    let strGlass: String
    let strInstructions: String
    
    let strIngredient1: String?
    let strIngredient2: String?
    let strIngredient3: String?
    let strIngredient4: String?
    let strIngredient5: String?
    let strIngredient6: String?
    let strIngredient7: String?
    let strIngredient8: String?
    let strIngredient9: String?
    let strIngredient10: String?
    
    var strMeasure1: String?
    var strMeasure2: String?
    var strMeasure3: String?
    var strMeasure4: String?
    var strMeasure5: String?
    var strMeasure6: String?
    var strMeasure7: String?
    var strMeasure8: String?
    var strMeasure9: String?
    var strMeasure10: String?
    
    // --- here adjust to your needs, could also use a computed property
    func allIngredients() -> [Ingredient] {
      return [
        Ingredient(name: strIngredient1 ?? "", amount: strMeasure1 ?? ""),
        Ingredient(name: strIngredient2 ?? "", amount: strMeasure2 ?? ""),
        Ingredient(name: strIngredient3 ?? "", amount: strMeasure3 ?? ""),
        Ingredient(name: strIngredient4 ?? "", amount: strMeasure4 ?? ""),
        Ingredient(name: strIngredient5 ?? "", amount: strMeasure5 ?? ""),
        Ingredient(name: strIngredient6 ?? "", amount: strMeasure6 ?? ""),
        Ingredient(name: strIngredient7 ?? "", amount: strMeasure7 ?? ""),
        Ingredient(name: strIngredient8 ?? "", amount: strMeasure8 ?? ""),
        Ingredient(name: strIngredient9 ?? "", amount: strMeasure9 ?? ""),
        Ingredient(name: strIngredient10 ?? "", amount: strMeasure10 ?? "")
    ].filter{!$0.name.isEmpty}
  }

}

struct Ingredient: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var amount: String
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I have gotten it working kinda like I want to, the divider is not showing up but ill try figure it out before asking :) Thanks again!

Comment: glad it helped. Try this for Divider: `Divider().frame(height: 2).background(Color.blue)`

Comment: Sorry, trying to learn as much as possible. From your solution there is ".filter{!$0.name.isEmpty}" does this mean it just checks the array and removes ones where the "name" is empty? Thanks!

Comment: yes, simple as that. Strictly, just get all non-empty names.

Answer (score 0):

change you struct to

```
struct Drink: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let strDrink : String
    let strInstructions: String
    let strDrinkThumb: String?
    let strIngredients: [String] = []
}
```

wherever you want to loop through ingredients you can use `drink.strIngredients` array

Answer (score 0):

First of all your design cannot work because you are ignoring the root object, a struct with a key `drinks`

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let drinks : [Drink]
}
```

A possible solution is to write a custom `init` method. However this a bit tricky because you have to inject dynamic `CodingKeys` to be able to decode the ingredients in a loop

First create a custom `CodingKey` struct

```
struct AnyKey: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int?
    
    init?(stringValue: String) {  self.stringValue = stringValue  }
    init?(intValue: Int) { return nil } // will never be called
}
```

In the `Drink` struct – by the way it's supposed to be named in singular form – specify a second container, create the ingredient keys on the fly, decode the ingredients in a loop and append the results to an array until the value is `nil`. Somebody should tell the owners of the service that their JSON structure is very amateurish. As you have to specify the `CodingKeys` anyway I mapped the keys to more meaningful and less redundant struct member names.

```
struct Drink: Decodable, Identifiable {
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case name = "strDrink", instructions = "strInstructions", thumbnail = "strDrinkThumb"
    }
    
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let instructions: String
    let thumbnail: URL
    let ingredients: [String]
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.instructions = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .instructions)
        self.thumbnail = try container.decode(URL.self, forKey: .thumbnail)
        var counter = 1
        var temp = [String]()
        let anyContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyKey.self)
        while true {
            let ingredientKey = AnyKey(stringValue: "strIngredient\(counter)")!
            guard let ingredient = try anyContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: ingredientKey) else { break }
            temp.append(ingredient)
            counter += 1
        }
        ingredients = temp
    }
}
```

In the view display the ingredients like this

```
struct IngredientView: View {
    let drink : Drink
 
    var body: some View {
        GroupBox() {
            DisclosureGroup("Drink Ingredience") {
                ForEach(drink.ingredients) { ingredient in
                    Divider().padding(.vertical, 2)
                    HStack {
                        Group {
                            Text(ingredient)
                        }
                        .font(Font.system(.body).bold())
                        Spacer(minLength: 25)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, i did have the root just didnt realise i should have posted it here (Newbie). Ill check out your solution though, thanks!